# class-specific neural networks vs overall network

Tags: classification, neural-networks, ensemble-learning

Let's say I am working in a classification setting, like MNIST for instance, and imagine that I have 10 neural networks which are all slightly different and each perform very well on one unique class.

How would you go about using these networks and putting them into one meta neural network which would take advantage of the specialisation of the other 10?

Comment: Is the output of each network binary? If not, how good is each network at the tasks that are not its specialty?

Comment: No, each network has 10 outputs (one for each class). They are just slightly worse than if you train a network with no speciality in mind (just regular training as you would do on MNIST).

Comment: I would experiment 1. averaging all of the networks' outputs and 2. for a given example, select the class with the highest softmax score in all of the networks. I would expect 1 to work best because of the power of ensembles, but you could just keep what does best in the validation set

Comment: thanks for the ideas, i shall try that out.